# invert multinomial logit link with three unknown

Tags: statistics

I am attempting to invert the multinomial logit link with three variables.  I can do it with two variables, but I do not know how to do it with three.

A multinomial logit function for three states, i.e., three probabilities, $a, b, c$ is written as follows:

$a = \frac{e^{x}} {(1 + e^{x} + e^{y})}$

$b = \frac{e^{y}} {(1 + e^{x} + e^{y})}$

$c = 1 - a - b$

These three probabilities are defined by the parameters $x$ and $y$.  If we know $x$ and $y$ we can obtain $a$, $b$ and $c$.

However, given $a, b, c$, how do we obtain $x$ and $y$?  One way is to use multinomial logistic regression.  However, there should be a closed form solution in which $x$ and $y$ are obtained using basic algebra.  I can obtain the closed form solution for two parameters, $x$ and $y$:

$x = \log(\frac{a  (1 - b) + (a  b)}{ (1 - a)  (1 - b) - a  b})$

$y = \log(\frac{b  (1 - a) + (b  a) }{ (1 - b)  (1 - a) - b  a})$

Which simplifies to:

$x = \log(\frac{a}{1 - a - b})$

$y = \log(\frac{b}{1 - a - b})$

How can I obtain the closed form solution when there are three parameters $x, y, z\;$?

$a = \frac{e^{x}} {(1 + e^{x} + e^{y} + e^{z})}$

$b = \frac{e^{y}} {(1 + e^{x} + e^{y} + e^{z})}$

$c = \frac{e^{z}} {(1 + e^{x} + e^{y} + e^{z})}$

$d = 1 - a - b - c$

Comment: what is the meaning of the 3rd equation c=1-a-b? Why do you need this? The last equation c=1-a-b-c seems to be nonsense.

Comment: Why do you write a(1-b)+(ab) instead of a?

Comment: Why not work out the explicit expression for $c$ first ? for the first case $c = 1 - a - b = \frac{1}{1+e^x + e^y}$, so $e^x = \frac{a}{c} \implies \cdots$. The rest is similar.

Comment: The very last equation should probably have a $d$, not a $c$, on the left hand side.

Comment: @BarryCipra  Thank you.  That was a typo probably introduced when applying the revised formatting.

Comment: @miracle173  I derived those equations through a long series of increments that have since been deleted from the question.  I did not attempt to simplify the final equations, but could do so.  At the time I simply moved on the the system of three equations.

Comment: @miracle173 The last equation contained a typo probably introduced when revising the formatting.  This equation is needed so that all probabilities sum to one.  It might not be necessary to convey the mathematics but is critical for statistical estimation.

Comment: I think simplification of the solution for case of two and three variables could lead us immediately to the solution of the problem for n variables.

Answer (score 2):

For every fixed number of variables, you are considering, for every $i$,

> $$a_i=\frac{e^{x_i}}{1+s}$$

where

> $$s=\sum_ie^{x_i}$$

and

> $$z=\frac1{1+s}$$

and you are asking how to *invert* this system, that is, how to deduce the collection $(x_i)$ from the collection $(a_i)$ and $z$, or even, from $(a_i)$ only.

To solve this, consider that $$z+\sum_ia_i=1$$ hence, for every $i$, $$e^{x_i}=a_i\cdot(1+s)=\frac{a_i}z$$ that is,

> $$x_i=\log a_i-\log z=\log\left(\frac{a_i}{1-\sum\limits_ka_k}\right)$$

Comment: Rereading this post, I see that its content was entirely, albeit more concisely, explained by @achillehui in a comment on main posted 6 hours before it, with no visible reaction or understanding from the OP.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to solve
$$\begin{eqnarray}
a_1 &=& \frac{e^{x_1}} {1 + \sum_{i=1}^n e^{x_i}}\\
&\ldots&  \tag{1}\\
a_n &=& \frac{e^{x_n}} {1 + \sum_{i=1}^n e^{x_i}}\\
\end{eqnarray}
$$
with constants $$a_1,\ldots,a_n$$
and variables $$x_1,\ldots,x_n$$
then set 
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
u_1&=&e^{x_1} \\
&\ldots&  \tag{2}\\
u_n&=&e^{x_n} 
\end{eqnarray}
$$
and substitute in $(1)$ and multiply each equation by its denominator and you have

$$\begin{eqnarray}
a_1 + \sum_{i=1}^n a_1 u_i&=& u_1\\
&\ldots&  \tag{3}\\
a_n + \sum_{i=1}^n a_1 u_i&=& u_n\\
\end{eqnarray}
$$

This is a linear equation with variables $u_i.$ You can solve this numerically or algebraically with the well known methods for linear equations.

Then you can so the back substitution to get the $x_i.$

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
x_1&=&\log{u_1} \\
&\ldots&  \tag{4}\\
x_n&=&\log{u_n} 
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Answer (score -3):

Solve each variable $x$, $y$ and $z$ as a function of the other two.

$x = \log(\frac{(a + a  e^{y} + a  e^{z})}  {(1 - a)})$

$y = \log(\frac{(b + b  e^{x} + b  e^{z})}  {(1 - b)})$

$z = \log(\frac{(c + c  e^{x} + c  e^{y})}  {(1 - c)})$

Then:

Substitute $x$ into the equation for $y$.

Substitute $x$ into the equation for $z$.

Substitute $y$ into the equation for $x$.

Substitute $y$ into the equation for $z$.

Substitute $z$ into the equation for $x$.

And substitute $z$ into the equation for $y$.

Each parameter $x$, $y$ and $z$ is now expressed as a function of just one of the other two.

To express each parameter as a function of itself, substitute, for example, the equation expressing $x$ as a function of $y$ into the function expressing $y$ as a function of $x$.

Once these three equations are simplified we have:

$x = \log(-(a * c - a) / (c^2 + (b+a-2)*c + (a - 1)*b - a + 1 - a * b))$

$y = \log(-(b * c - b) / (c^2 + (b+a-2)*c + (a - 1)*b - a + 1 - a * b))$

$z = \log(((1-b)*c) / (((b+a-1)*c+b^2+(a-2)*b-a+1) - (a*c)))$